# What do the friction coefficients mean and why are they so large in the DRCSim Atlas URDF files?

Tags: gazebo, drcsim, friction

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been looking through the URDF specifications of the Atlas robot from DRC Sim. I noticed that there are two mu values and that they are quite large for what I would expect for a coefficient of friction. I've done some Googling but haven't found a definitive answer on what exactly the coefficient's mean and why the coefficients are larger than 1 in the models.

I found on ODE's wiki some information about the friction coefficients.
http://ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_Concepts#Friction_Approximation
However, it mentions that there are two approximation methods. So my first question is, which one does Gazebo use by default and which one does the DRC Sim use?

I found a few more references to the coefficients in the ODE manual here http://ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_All&printable=yes#Contact

I think that this section in the manual explains the difference between mu1 and mu2 and what the fdir1 and fdir2 parameters in the URDF means, but if it doesn't please let me know.

However, what I'm still not understanding is why there are mu values in the URDF that are above 1. Especially because in the newer SDF format specification it explicitly says that mu should be a value between 0 and 1. http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.3.html#mu

So my second question is why are the mu values so high in the URDF specification of the Atlas robot?

---

Also I wasn't sure if here or the ros answers site was more appropriate for this question. So I've posted in both places. Here is the other question. http://answers.ros.org/question/56178/what-do-the-friction-coefficients-mean-and-why-are-they-so-large-in-the-drcsim-atlas-urdf-files/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1512/what-do-the-friction-coefficients-mean-and-why-are-they-so-large-in-the-drcsim-atlas-urdf-files?/) by [rhololkeolke](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/230/rhololkeolke/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo uses the [dContactApprox1](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e7a0b8953af9bcc369c05436e3aae1b280777f5a/gazebo/physics/ode/ODEPhysics.cc?at=default#cl-818) option [without the fdir1](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e7a0b8953af9/gazebo/sdf/1.3/surface.sdf?at=default#cl-23) option by default.

[fdir1](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e7a0b8953af9bcc369c05436e3aae1b280777f5a/gazebo/sdf/1.3/surface.sdf?at=default#cl-23) is a `Vector3` specifying the direction of `mu1` in the collision local reference frame.  If left unspecified as `(0, 0, 0)`, `mu1` and `mu2` will align along `x` and `y`-axis of the world reference frame.  In the atlas case, the `fdir1` is specified to be `(1, 0, 0)`, so `mu1` will always act along the "heel-to-toe" direction.

The friction coefficients will be updated by
an existing [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/125/unthrottle-ros-controller-update-rates-for/diff), changes have been made to [use `mu` of 0.9](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/355f8db74a17c8f7e611dca3ac4fa130fcb1a5f2/ros/atlas_description/urdf/atlas.gazebo?at=issue_123#cl-59) for atlas feet.  This value may change when we get more realistic friction coefficient approximations.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

OK. So with dContactApprox on, the friction model should be the "cone" approximated
as a square-base pyramid, as shown here, right?

http://ode-wiki.org/wiki/index.php?title=Manual:_Concepts#Collision_handling

That should overestimate friction by up to **sqrt(2)** depending on the direction, which is probably good enough for basic legged locomotion.

If mu = mu1 = mu2 are equal, then for

**|Ft| < |Fn| * mu**

there should be no slippage, right?

Is all that the case, and does it work reasonably well?

---

Originally posted by [John Nagle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/395/john-nagle/) with karma: 66 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-06-19**:
fairly well, see http://youtu.be/JVe4YAkhVMI (corresponding world file https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/de6b97b7d61c87a71f075e988958a0863e50376d/sdf/worlds/test_friction.world?at=default).

**Comment by [fireflies343](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47595/fireflies343/) on 2021-05-20**:
This link (to the bitbucket file) is now broken. It would greatly help me to take a look at this file. Can an updated link be posted?